# Абстракция «сокрытие информации»?

Tags: ооп, инкапсуляция

Смотрю [курс по c#](https://itvdn.com/ru/video/csharp-essential), и вот на одном из уроков посвященному динамическим и анонимным типам, а также "языку" LINQ. Автор видео курса говорит, что сокрытие информации как абстракцию можно разделить условно на три типа:

- сокрытие реализации типов класса
- инкапсуляция вариации как частей программных систем
- сокрытие типов данных - тип var

Кто мне может подробнее объяснить эти три пункта, что имел ввиду автор, говоря про них, и что имел ввиду вообще, говоря, что можно разделит абстракцию сокрытия информации на эти три состовляющие?

P.S Возможности пообщаться с автором видеокурса у меня нет.

Comment: Про var - это фантазия автора курсов. Var сделан для того, чтобы позволииь компилятору вывести тип переменной. Он ничего и не от кого не скрывает. Тип все равно есть, и он явно виден.

Comment: а в курсе разве они не объясняются?

Comment: нет, не объясняется. это вообще сказано вскользь.

Comment: А ссылка на курс?

Comment: https://itvdn.com/ru/video/csharp-essential

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ух… Как же много вопросов вызывают моменты, указанные в этом вопросе.

> сокрытие информации как абстракцию

У меня, честно говоря, чуть мозг не сломался от этой фразы. В моем понимании, сокрытие информации (information hiding) и абстракция (abstraction) – это две вещи, которые всегда идут совместно. Чтобы «абстрагироваться» от чего-то, нам нужно выбросить из рассмотрения несущественные детали и сосредоточиться на ключевых аспектах этого «чего-то».

В этом плане, сокрытие информации – это техника, которая позволяет абстракции существовать, но само сокрытие информации не является «абстракцией». Это скорее техника или принцип.

Теперь я попробую интерпретировать, что имел ввиду автор под каждом из пунктов ниже:

> сокрытие реализации типов класса

Тут опять-таки, язык довольно сложный, но я подразумеваю, что речь идет о классическом ОО-полиморфизме. Иерархия наследования – это один из классических способов создания абстракции. Если мы работаем с переменной типа ‘Stream’, то нам (обычно) все равно, какой конкретный поток мы используем. Это может быть ‘MemoryStream’, может быть ‘FileStream’, а может быть что-то еще. Эта информация скрыта от нас. При этом мы «абстрагируеся» от конкретного типа «потока».

Нужно сказать, что «абстракция» и «инкапсуляция» существует даже без использования наследования. Класс ‘List’ скрывает от нас детали реализации, например того, как он растет внутри – по экспоненте или по одному элементу, даже когда мы используем этот тип не полиморфно. Аналогично, StringBuilder скрывает способ роста, а класс ‘ConfigurationReader’ может скрывать источник получения конфигурации.

> инкапсуляция вариации как частей программных систем

И снова, мне довольно сложно понять эту фразу, но я думаю, что имеется ввиду следующее. Допустим, у нас есть приложение, которое получает данные из некоторого источника, например, базы данных. Мы можем размазать информацию об этом по всему приложению: формочки могут ходить напрямую в базу, туда же может ходить логика, которая считает что-то очень важное. Или же мы можем спрятать наше решение в определенном модуле: «источнике данных». Сделать мы это можем потому, что хотим изолировать ошибки/изменения требований от всей остальной системы.

Если мы решим в будущем, что данные должны приходить из другой базы, из файла или читаться с сервера, то нам не придется изменять все приложение. Мы заменим релазиацию одного модуля и все (да, обычно подобные изменения сопряжены с рядом сложностей, но идея должна быть понятной).

Таким образом мы выделяем кусок системы, который может поменяться, от всей остальной системы, останавливая, таким образом, каскад возможных изменений.

> сокрытие типов данных - тип var

Это самый спорный тип сокрытия информации.

‘var’ в языке C# ведь ничего не скрывает от компилятора. Это лишь синтаксический сахар, который позволяет убрать с глаз читателя конкретный тип переменной.

В некотором плане, я согласен, что от читателя тип скрыт, то позволяет ему (читателю) сосредоточиться на главном – логике приложения, и «абстрагироваться» от конкретных типов переменных, вовлеченных в эту логику.

Я когда-то довольно подробно писал на эту тему в посте [“Инкапсуляция и сокрытие информации”](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2016/09/encapsulation-and-information-hiding.html). И вот пара наиболее ценных (ИМХО) цитат оттуда:

> **Сокрытие информации – это сокрытие деталей проектирования, которые могут измениться в будущем, для ограничения каскадных изменений в программной системе и для упрощения ее разработки и сопровождения.**
>
> **Сокрытие информации – это принцип проектирования, который позволяет упаковывать определенные знания в «коробочку», которую можно будет аккуратненько спрятать в одном месте, перепрятать в будущем или изменить ее содержимое.**

Answer (score -3):

Я вам расскажу очень простейшим вариантом.
Я рекомендую читать книги GOF 'Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software' и Совершенный код 'Code Complete' и паттерны проектирования 'Head First Design Patterns'.

В ООП инкапсуляция разделяется на три части (и здесь подразумевается абстракция сокрытие информации).
Эти три раздела очень хорошо используются в паттернах проектирования, надо анализировать.

Oтветы

1. **Cокрытие типов данных** "динамический и неявно типизированные" (`dynamic` , `var`).
   Это означает, что мы используем некий протокол, то есть **инкапсулируем/скрываем (здесь подразумеваете сокрыта реализация типов данных то есть не меняется)** и он как будто бы полиморфным образом меняется, и это и есть абстракция сокрытие информации. **У нас есть общий Тип и он варьируется (абстракция сокрытие информации)** (здесь подразумевается, что могут варьироваться полиморфным образом, здесь подразумевается общая структура типов. А не подразумевается сопоставление и детальная работа `dynamic` или `var` !).
2. **Сокрытие реализации** а здесь объясняется **модификатор доступа** и **приведение к базовому типу полиморфным привидением (UpCast -> здесь тоже инкапсулируем/скрываем детали дочерних классов)** это уже простейшее понятие, думаю что вы это знаете.
3. **Инкапсуляция вариаций/Сокрытие частей программных систем.** Когда мы в объектно-ориентированном программировании разделяем ответственности или делаем декомпозицию предметной области. У нас что получается: подсистемы (можем сказать, такие отношения являются композицией) и его собирательные понятия (который мы взаимодействуем) **'я очень жестко определил но просто ты чтобы понял'**. Вот внизу я показал пример машина (Car) - это собирательное понятие, которые мы и **инкапсулируем/скрываем его части (дополнительно здесь подразумевается упростить сложность)** , двигатель (Engine) и карбюратор (Carburetor)
   таким способом мы собираем машину. **У нас получается (собирательное понятие)машина (Car) делегирует под системы и машина здесь инкапсулирует/скрывает под системы** **(здесь не имеет значения абстрактное класс/интерфейс или конкретный класс (под системы), и эти два варианта содержают Инкапсуляция вариаций).**

Ну если вы не поняли суть **Инкапсуляция вариаций** опять-таки я вам рекомендую читать книги надо узнать объектно-ориентированный анализ и проектирование (декомпозиция предметной области) и так далее.

**И хорошо вспомнить одно из принципов 'Инкапсулируйте ,то что изменяется'.**
Я могу привести примеры паттернов проектирования, которые используют эти понятия к примеру:
(паттерн команда , паттерн состояние , паттерн  стратегия , паттерн фасад) и так далее.
Пожалуйста прочитайте книгу 'GOF' страница **328** 'Обсуждение паттернов поведения (Инкапсуляция вариаций)'.

Пример для **(1)** пункта.

```
 //инкапсулируем/скрываем
 //абстрактный сокрытие информации - > var
 var Car = new Car(null);
 //инкапсулируем/скрываем
 //абстрактный сокрытие информации - > var
 var Integer = 15155;
 //инкапсулируем/скрываем
 //абстрактный сокрытие информации - > dynamic
 dynamic dStr = "asdasdasd";
 DataOperation(dStr);
```

Пример для **(3)** пункта. Я этикеты поставил (для сопоставлений) который написал на **(3)** третьем пункте (внимательно читайте!).

```
//абстракция - контракт
interface IEngine
{
   bool TurnOn();
   bool TurnOff();
}

// подсистема
// локализация и скрытие информации
// инкапсулируем/скрываем
class XAFullEngine : IEngine
{
    private bool _switch;
    private int _trm;
    public XAFullEngine()
    {
        _switch = false;
        _trm = 0;
    }

    private void breakTrm()
    {
        if(_trm >= 99)
            throw new Exception("Breaked!");

    }

    public bool TurnOff()
    {
        breakTrm();
        if (_switch == true)
        {
            _switch = false;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    public bool TurnOn()
    {
        breakTrm();
        if (_switch == false)
        {
            _trm += 10;
            _switch = true;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}

// подсистема
// локализация и скрытие информации
// инкапсулируем/скрываем
class SSEasyEngine : IEngine
{
    private bool _switch;
    public SSEasyEngine()
    {
        _switch = false;

    }

    public bool TurnOff()
    {

        if (_switch == true)
        {
            _switch = false;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    public bool TurnOn()
    {
        if (_switch == false)
        {
            _switch = true;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}

// собирательные понятия (дополнительно здесь подразумевается упростить сложность) , (делегирование подсистем)
// (ассоциативный объект),   (абстракция и формирования высокоуровневые сущность).
class Car
{
    // И хорошо вспомнить понятие одна из принципов 'Инкапсулируйте то, что изменяется'.
  // здесь не имеет значения       абстрактное/интерфейс класс или конкретное класс поэтому и два варианта 
  // является Инкапсуляция вариаций!
// private XAFullEngine _engine; 
    private IEngine _engine;

    public Car(IEngine Engine)
    {
        this._engine = Engine;
    }

    public void TurnOn()
    {
        _engine.TurnOn();
    }

    public void TurnOff()
    {
        _engine.TurnOff();
    }
}
```

Пример использования: симулирование паттерна стратегия.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //                менять полиморфным образом
        Car bwm = new Car(new SSEasyEngine());
       // делегирование подсистемы
        bwm.TurnOn();

        //                менять полиморфным образом
        Car toyota = new Car(new XAFullEngine());
       // делегирование подсистемы
        toyota.TurnOn();
    }
```

Нo в диаграмме классов я не абстрагировал, извиняюсь!

Вот диаграмма классов пример для **3** пункта.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: dynamic и var - это совершенно разные вещи и к сокрытию информации они вообще никакого отношения не имеют.

Comment: определение не идёт а каким-то сопоставлением данных Да это другие типы . Здесь идет определение контрактный инкапсуляция .))) я написал наверху книгу или хотите рекомендую видеокурс.

Comment: Здесь идет скрытие и варьирование.

Comment: Поставил (пока) минус. Во-первых, var - это вообще не о том. во-вторых, не приведено примеров кода. В-третьих, рисунок не в тему. В-четвёртых, нет даже примера на private в классе. Мне кажется, ответ нужно значительно переработать.

Comment: @AK у меня не было времени но я поправлю с примерами. я вам рекомендую читать , они ставить минусы. во-вторых спасибо большое за комментарий.) нет проблем.

Comment: Я готов снять свой минус, когда/если вы доработаете ответ.

Comment: У Вас есть редкий шанс заработать значок "Давление сообщества"

Comment: @vp_arth Спасибо большое за комментарий.Ну я не для значок написал это пусть будет минусом нет проблем. Просто грустно что я даю книги референсы никто не даёт на это внимание.Ну я вижу что люди не хорошо понимают и у них низкий уровень знания объектно-ориентированное программирование. опять-таки спасибо за комментарий.